# Getting updated model in onActivityResult using gson? Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, android-intent, adapter, onactivityresult

I have a horizontal adapter which has Edit option. On selecting edit it opens up new activity. After editing it comes back to horizontal adapter. I am trying to update the model class in the adapter using onActivityResult. but trace is saying

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=78, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.codon.masterpiece/com.codon.masterpiece.ui.home.FullScreenSelf}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4335)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.codon.masterpiece.ui.home.SelfHorizontalScroll.instantiateItem(SelfHorizontalScroll.java:109)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:1086)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:3097)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:291)
        at com.codon.masterpiece.ui.home.FullScreenSelf.onActivityResult(FullScreenSelf.java:237)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7355)
```

Here is my onActivityResult

```
 if (requestCode == 78 && data != null) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String artworkData = data.getStringExtra("ArtworkData");
                TypeToken<ArtworksData> token = new TypeToken<ArtworksData>() {
                };
                ArtworksData artworksData = gson.fromJson(artworkData, token.getType());

                arrayList.set(position, artworksData);

                selfHorizontalScroll.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Redirecting to edit activity

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.edit_menu) {
                    //call edit art activity and pass task id

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, EditArtwork.class);
                    //Intent newintent = ctx.getIntent();
                    // Bundle bundle = newintent.getExtras();
                    String taskID = feed.getId() + "", imageUrl = "";

                    imageUrl = feed.getImg1() + "";
                    intent.putExtra("artwork_id", taskID);
                    intent.putExtra("image_url", imageUrl);
                    intent.putExtra("position", ((FullScreenSelf) ctx).viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    //intent.putExtra("wishtosell", feed.getWishtosell());
                    Activity origin_new = (Activity) ctx;
                    origin_new.startActivityForResult(intent, 78);

                }
```

Method in edit activity

```
if ("False".equals(error)){
                        kProgressHUD.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(EditArtwork.this, "Artwork updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("Upload", jsonObject.toString());
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JsonObject data = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data");
                        TypeToken<ArtworksData> token = new TypeToken<ArtworksData>() {
                        };
                        ArtworksData artworksData = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), token.getType());

                        //EditArtwork.this.onBackPressed();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("ArtworkData", artworksData.toString());
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
```

its crashing here. at the instantiateItem method in the adapter.

```
 final boolean[] hasLiked = {feed.getLiked()};
    final boolean[] redirect = {feed.getBrSent()};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: @MikeM. edited my quetion with stack trace

Comment: Unless your `ArtworksData` class's `toString()` method returns its JSON representation, I really don't think you want to create an `ArtworksData` instance in the edit `Activity`. You're creating the `ArtworksData` in the first `Activity`, so you just want to pass back the JSON, right?

Comment: @MikeM. no mike, I am calling an api in Edit activity from which it returns a new instance of ArtworksData (Updated). Then I want to return that back to adapter and update the adapter.

Comment: "it returns a new instance of ArtworksData" – It doesn't look like that. It looks like your API returns JSON, and you're creating an `ArtworksData` instance from that yourself. I'm saying that you don't want to do that in the edit `Activity`. You're doing it in the first `Activity`, so you need to pass back the JSON, not `ArtworksData#toString()`, which – unless you've overridden it – is likely returning something like `com.your.package.ArtworksData@1234567`.

Comment: But I am not sending the ArtworksData in the intent when directing to Edit activity. So how would I update that instance.

Comment: You're not updating anything. You're creating a new `ArtworksData` instance, but currently, you're trying to do it twice – once in the edit `Activity`, and again in `onActivityResult()`. You only need to do it once, in `onActivityResult()`. To do that there, you need to pass back the JSON.

Comment: Okay, I passed json from Edit activity by  intent.putExtra("ArtworkData", data.toString()); but still it is not updating. I am also sending back the position where it needs to be updated

Comment: It doesn't look like it. In the posted code, the only extra you're putting on the returned `Intent` is `"ArtworkData"`. Did you forget to put `"position"`, too?

Comment: Sorry, I have added now. Still the same issue Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Comment: Wait, what? Was it not crashing before you added that extra? Your last comment made it sound like it just wasn't updating, but still running. In either case, what's the current Exception message?

Comment: No change in the Exception message. I have edited question with the whole exception message. It's crashing now as well.

Comment: No change? That's a completely different `Exception`. That `Exception` is happening in `SelfHorizontalScroll#instantiateItem()`.

Comment: OK, I didn't see the little snippet you added at the end. That means that either `getLiked()` or `getBrSent()` has a null field. There's not enough information here to determine why that is.

Comment: No but when I am coming back to this horizontal screen . It's not crashing. It has getLiked and getBrSent. Only when I am coming back from Edit activity it is getting null. Why is that?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't even know what `feed` is. This is not the original error.

Comment: The earlier error is also coming with this. Anyway thanks for taking ur time man. I'll check my code again. Really appreciate ur efforts

Comment: You'll still get the `Failure delivering result` error when anything goes wrong in `onActivityResult()`. The original `Exception` message was `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`. That's the message I was talking about. (You have to scroll all the way to the right to see it.) You got that one fixed, though, because now you're getting that new `NullPointerException`. Anyhoo, no problem. Glad we got one issue solved, at least. Cheers!